# optimizing functions (memory) in lisp - trie data structure

Tags: lisp, trie

I'm a lisp beginner and I'm trying to write a package that defines a class for a trie and reads the entirety of the scrabble dictionary in to it. The struct acts as a node, each of which has an association list that keeps track of letters that stem from it (leading to other subtries).

Here is my code for the class

```
(DEFCLASS n-trie ()
  ((word :accessor word
         :initform 'nil
         :initarg :word)
   (word-count :accessor wcount
               :initform 0
               :initarg :wcount)
   (next-letters :accessor next-letters
                 :initform 'nil
                 :initarg :next-letters)))
```

Here is my add word function

```
(defun add-word (string trie) ;;iterative method for looping through string
  (let ((s (coerce string 'list))
        (tri trie))
    (dolist (item s)
      (cond
       ((assoc item (next-letters tri))
        (incf (wcount tri))
        (setf tri (cdr (assoc item (next-letters tri)))))
       (t
        (incf (wcount tri))
        (setf (next-letters tri) (acons item (make-instance 'n-trie) (next-letters tri)))
        (setf tri (cdr (assoc item (next-letters tri)))))))
    (setf (word tri) string)))
```

and here is the function that opens my file (scrabble dictionary) and reads each line

```
(defun read-words (file trie)
  (let((str (open file)))
    (labels ((rec (tri)
                  (let ((line (read-line str nil nil)))
                    (cond 
                     (line (add-word line tri)
                           (rec tri))
                     (t (close str)
                        trie)))))
      (rec trie))))
```

Whenever I try to load the entire dictionary, I get a stack overflow. There are over 100k words in the scrabble dictionary, and it's failing at 6000...something is wrong with my memory usage, but I can't seem to tell what.

Is there something that I am doing in these definitions that is inherently expensive memory-wise? I tried making the trie node a struct instead of a class, and got similar results. I also had a recursive algorithm for adding a word from the dictionary, but it was just as bad.

I've been struggling with this for hours, and i'm a little frustrated...

Comment: I tried implementing with hash tables at first... I thought a-lists would be more efficeint. The point of this implementation is that each letter in a word should be in a separate sub-trie, only creating a new sub-trie if a subtrie branch for that letter does not exist. Information about words that terminate at certain subtries and how many words exist under a subtrie is also part of the goal (hence why I thought to keep track of this info by having association lists of n-trie instances.

I agree it does not seem like the most efficient way to store the info...

Comment: also (next-letters tri) is just accessing the (next-letters) attribute of the n-trie class...so that shouldn't really be that big of a memory issue.

Comment: What is the value in your hash table for each key? Is it another node?How do you traverse the tree otherwise?

Comment: ok i'm going to mess around with that idea for a while. will report back with any breakthroughs. thanks for the help!

Comment: tried out your implementation, pretty sure you are doing what i want to do, however I'm running into an error that I ran out of heap space... I'm  using allegro common lisp, are you using a different interpreter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I would change is the function `read-words`. It uses tail-recursion and looks like in Scheme. That's not idiomatic in Common Lisp. Use `WITH-OPEN-FILE` to open a file and use a loop construct to read the lines. If the Common Lisp system does not optimize the tail recursion, this recursion already creates a stack overflow on large text files.

So:

- don't use tail recursion, where not necessary and where you know that your CL implementation actually supports it and understands it. For example high debug modes usual prevent tail recursion optimization.
- use `WITH-OPEN-FILE`. Don't use `OPEN`/`CLOSE`.
- use `IF` instead of `COND` - especially when we deal with a normal true/false predicate.

Comment: thanks, i'll give that a shot and report back. Just out of curiosity...I always thought that using cond was better practice in CL than using if...

Comment: this seemed to work well. thanks.

It still doesn't load my full dictionary...i'm running into the heap limit of my allegro cl free edition.

any suggestions on solutions for that?